# Unknown Provider for angular when creating filter in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

My filter `($index % 4 == 0)`is throwing a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: (FilterProvider <- (Filter`

**Question:**

**How do I make this filter work so that I can create a wraping div with a class of .row; for every 4 inner items?**

**HTML:**

```
//Create a  div with a class of .row for every 4 images

<div  ng-repeat="(key, pageValue) in adPageData.pages" ng-class="row | ( $index % 4 == 0)">
//creates a div with a class of c4-sm which means 25% width
    <div class="c4-sm" ng-repeat="(hotspotsKey, hotspotsValue) in pageValue.hotspots">
        <img ng-src="{{hotspotsValue.tooltip_data.image}}" alt="" />

    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.c4-sm{
  @include span(4);
}
.row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this, you can't provide _any_ expression after the pipe (|) - it needs to be a filter function created and registered as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the filter, you can use the `ng-class` this way:

```
<div ng-repeat=".." ng-class="{ row: ($index % 4 == 0) }">
```